# Spacing in fractions

Tags: math-mode, spacing, fractions

I have a fraction whose denominator is a fraction again.
I want to write the denominator in parantheses, but I have the feeling that the space is not really nice.

[image]

The lower term is nice from the spacing, but parantheses destroy it.
I would love to see the whole fraction in the denominator a bit up.
Is that possible?
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\[
    \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\left(\frac{x}{\log(x)}\right)} = 1. 
\]

\[
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\frac{x}{\log(x)}} = 1. 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `\limits` into `\[...\]`: is unnecessary? Use the package `amsmath` and `\dfrac` in `\left(\frac{x}{\log(x)}\right)`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `\left` and `\right` to size the parentheses in the denominator term; use `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead. For that matter, does the denominator term really need parentheses? And do you need the parentheses in `\log(x)`?

Do also give some thought to replacing the `\frac`-format denominator term with an inline-fraction expression. That way, the terms in the numerator and denominator will all be rendered in `\textstyle` math mode.

Finally, there's no need for the `\limits` qualifiers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\bigl(\frac{x}{\log(x)}\bigr)} =
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\frac{x}{\log x}} = 
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{x/\log x} = 1. 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 6):

Three answers appeared in the time it took me to write this up but I'm posting it anyway. You can use the `mathtools` package and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command to create paired delimiters that size correctly, using optional manual `\big`, `\Big`, etc.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ps}{(}{)}

\begin{document}
\[
    \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)} = 1. 
\]

\[
    \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\frac{x}{\log x}} = 1. 
\]

\[
    \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{ \ps{\frac{x}{\log x}} } = 1. 
\]

\[
    \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{ \ps[\big]{\frac{x}{\log x}} } = 1. 
\]

\[
    \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{ \ps[\Big]{\frac{x}{\log x}} } = 1. 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `\left` and `\right`, which set automatically the delimiters sizes, you can choose it manually with (from smaller to bigger) :

```tex
\bigl ... \bigr
\Bigl ... \bigr
\biggl ... \biggr
\Biggl ... \Biggr
```

For example, with `\bigl` and `\bigr` :

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\[
  \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\bigl(\frac{x}{\log(x)}\bigr)} = 1.
\]

\[
  \lim\_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\frac{x}{\log(x)}} = 1.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Into `\[...\]` \limits has not effect.

Comment: @Sebastiano OK, I edited the answer to remove it. Thanks.